# Java 8 Comma Separated String to Object property

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have three comma-separated lists (list of bus, car, cycle) and I am trying to write them into Java object properties using Java 8 streams.

Please find below what I have tried :

```
public class Traffic {

    public int car;
    public int bus;
    public int cycle;

    public Traffic(int car, int bus,int cycle){
        this.car = car;
        this.bus = bus;
        this.cycle = cycle;
    }

}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String bus = "5,9,15,86";
        String car = "6,12,18,51";
        String cycle = "81,200,576,894";
        String[] busArray = bus.split(",");
        String[] carArray = car.split(",");
        String[] cycleArray = cycle.split(",");

        List<Traffic> trafficList =
                Arrays.stream(values)
                        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                        .mapToObj((int i,j) -> new Traffic(i,j))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

I was struggling with getting all streams up and injected into object properties. (I want to create 4 objects in this case populating all 3 properties.)

Basically, I am looking for something like below:

```
List<Traffic> trafficList =
                Arrays.stream(carArray,busArray,cycleArray)
                        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                        .mapToObj((int i,j,k) -> new Traffic(i,j,k))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Do you expect to end up with 4 different objects of `Traffic`?

Comment: feels so bad to answer a wrongly asked question, then someone else gets the correct answer cuz the OP edits the question... :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create *4 objects* of Traffic then you can use the following :

```
List<Traffic> collect = IntStream.range(0, busArray.length)
                          .mapToObj(i -> new Traffic(Integer.parseInt(busArray[i]),
                                                     Integer.parseInt(carArray[i]),
                                                     Integer.parseInt(cycleArray[i])))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: And what if `carArray` has less elements than `busArray`? You took no care about an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Or you can write explicitly `IntStream.range(0, 4)`

Answer (score 0):

You just have to split your string and then map each value to your object.

Here I assume the value can be passed through the constructor of your `Traffic` object. If not, you can create it and set its value in 2 separate lines. The `mapToInt` is necessary if the `value` is expected to be an integer.

```
String original = "5,9,15,86";
String[] values = original.split(",");

List<Traffic> trafficList = 
   Arrays.stream(values)
      .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
      .map(Traffic::new) 
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @JavaMan have you noticed this answer also has the error i had before?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want an array, you can try the following

```
Arrays.stream("5,9,15,86".split(","))
        .map(Traffic::new)
        .toArray(Traffic[]::new);
```

If a `List<Traffic>` is also okay for you i recommend this one

```
Arrays.stream("5,9,15,86".split(","))
        .map(Traffic::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And lastly if you only have a constructor for `Integer` for example, you can map the stram to int like

```
Arrays.stream("5,9,15,86".split(","))
        .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
        .mapToObj(Traffic::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**EDIT**

I answered this question before the question was edited, that's why it is only a partial answer

**EDIT2**

Okay i got it, i used `map` instead of `mapToObj` what a huge mistake... But i found it out thanks to @JavaMan's helpful answers (notice that if you are using IntelliJ it offers you to replace `map` with `mapToObj`)

Comment: I'm afraid your solution never worked, as the solution you outlined would not have copied split value to the object property. Also, if you tried your code then it would give a compile error. In any case, dust is now settled on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Define a constructor in the class Traffic that takes an integer as argument and assigns it to value attribute in the class.

```
    static class Traffic {
      private int value;
      public Traffic(int value) {
        this.value = value;
      }
    }
```

Now assuming the comma delimited string is in a string commandList, something like below.

```
String commaList = "1,3,5,6,7,8,9,100";
```

Following stream instruction will return a list of Traffic objects with the value assigned.

```
    List<Traffic> listOfIntegers = 
      Arrays.asList(commaList.split(","))
        .stream()
        .map(e -> new Traffic(Integer.valueOf(e)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```